# RegEx Expression for Parenthesis Matching

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need some help coming up with a C# regular expression that can take a string like:

```
string input = "Test1='1' OR (Test2 = '2' OR (Test3 = '3')) OR (Test4 = '4')";
```

and return match items like:

```
1 => Test1='1' OR
2 => (Test2 = '2' OR (Test3 = '3'))
3 => OR
4 => (Test4 = '4')
```

Comment: the parentheses aren't balanced

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx)

To get you started.. here's a sample for the input you provided.

```
string pattern = @"(Test1='1' OR) \(Test2 = '2'";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
    {
       foreach(Group group in match.Groups)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(group);
       }
    }
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks I knew that much. What I need help with is the regex pattern. What you have as the pattern above is really the input.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: As I noted, I don' think this is helpful. I'm looking for the actual regex expression. That part is missing from your solution.

Comment: the regex expression is the `pattern`

Comment: have you even tried this yet? `input` is `"Test1='1' OR (Test2 = '2' OR (Test3 = '3')) OR (Test4 = '4')"`